# comparing two columns of two dataframe and finding miss matching

Tags: r

I have two different dataframes as below

```
df1 <- data.frame(state=letters[1:3],district=letters[4:6])

 state district
1     a        d
2     b        e
3     c        f
```

and df2

```
df2 <- data.frame(state=letters[1:3], district= c("e","d","f"))

  state district
1     a        e
2     b        d
3     c        f
```

I want to check whether districts of `df1` exists in `df2`? if not select state and district.
And If districts in `df1`  exists in `df2` does it belongs to exact same state in`df1` or not?
suppose district "d" belongs to state "a" in `df1` but district "d" belongs to state "b" in `df2` which is wrong.
What I am trying is:

```
'%noin%' <- Negate('%in%')

#creating unique id for df1
df1$uuid <- tolower(paste0(df1$state,"_",df1$district)) 

#creating unique id for df2
df2$uuid <- tolower(paste0(df2$state,"_",df2$district)) 

df_result <- df1 %>% filter(df1$uuid %noin% df2$uuid) %>% 
               select(state,district)

   state district
1     a        d
2     b        e
```

how can I select the right state in df2 which these districts belongs to?
what my expected output looks like is:

```
expected_output <- data.frame(state=c("a","b"), district=c("d","e"),state_in_df_2=c("b","a"))

 state   district   state_in_df_2
1     a        d             b
2     b        e             a
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `anti_join` and a `left_join` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(state=letters[1:3],district=letters[4:6])
df2 <- data.frame(state=letters[1:3], district= c("e","d","f"))

df1 %>% 
  anti_join(df2, by = c("state", "district")) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("district"), suffix = c("", "_in_df2"))
#>   state district state_in_df2
#> 1     a        d            b
#> 2     b        e            a
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with dplyr?

Comment: Hi. My approach already is the or at least one dplyr approach.

Comment: the problem with join is I can not pass function argument to it. That's why I asked if there is any other solution with dplyr

Comment: What you mean by „ I can not pass a function argument to join“? If you want to put the code inside a function, you could pass the dataframes as well as the column names to join by as arguments. Maybe you could clarify what you have in mind.

Comment: suppose I am defining a function which takes two data frame and some arguments as below:
```sample_tool <- function(sample,s_manteqa,village, tool,list_name,name,t_manteqa){
sample %>% anti_join(tool, by = c(s_manteqa = t_manteqa, Village_Name= name)) %>%  
            left_join(tool, by = c(Village_Name = name))
}
result <-sample_tool(sample,"Manteqa","Village_Name",tool,"village","name","manteqa")
```
When I call function it doesn't recognize arguments that has been passed to it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure If this will generalise in your case but you can try,

```
filter(merge(df1, df2, by = 'district'), state.x != state.y)

#  district state.x state.y
#1        d       a       b
#2        e       b       a
```

Comment: is there any way to do this with dplyr?